# How to generate UML diagram from a table

Tags: class, uml

I have a (single) table that I want to produce UML diagram from. The structure is as follows:

ID|Class|Sub-Class|Sub-Sub-Class|Property1|Property2|Property3...

So is there a way to produce the class diagram from this table?

Edit: Here is an example;

```
ID|Class |Sub-Class|Sub-Sub-Class|CanSwim|CanFly|Weight|
 1|Animal|Cat      |Tiger        |False  |False | 48kg |
 2|Animal|Cat      |Domestic Cat |False  |False | 4kg  |
 3|Animal|Fish     |Golden Fish  |True   |False |0.01kg|
 3|Human |NULL     |NULL         |True   |False |70kg  |
```

So the result would be a diagram consisting two classes one being Humans, another one being Animals with 2 sub classes, Fishes and Cats and Cats having two sub classes etc

Comment: The names alone are not helpful. What do they represent?

Comment: @ThomasKilian Imagine I have 3 levels of classes. Class is the name of the first level class for the entitty, Sub class is the name of the second level class which is a child of the specified 1st level class. Is that clear?

Comment: The result could also be one class called with properties for each of the columns. Based on this alone you cannot make the decision whether or not `Domestic Cat` should be a class, or merely a value in the enumeration `Sub-Sub-Class`

Comment: @GeertBellekens I know which properties are class/sub-class identifiers. The rest are just properties for those classes. I though there would be a tool which I could specify my class identifiers and it would take care of the properties for those classes. i.e "if a property exists in all subclasses of a class, show it as a property of a parent class not the sub class."

Comment: If you are looking for a tool then this is out of scope of SO

Answer (score 1):

There are of course many ways to realize this. A simple approach would be

[image]

where you just use enumerations for the classification.

A more sophisticated approach is to use a class structure which will itself clarify the sub-classing:

[image]

This allows for a finer grained specification of the sub-class. So you have just one reference to `Creature` which holds all the sub-classing information that is available. You could also add more information than just the name of the sub-classes.

Comment: My question is probably not clear enough. I can produce the diagram myself but I am looking for "the sophisticated way" which takes the table, and the class identifiers as input and take care of the properties automatically and draws the diagram. Now that I am writing this comment, I think I could produce a class definition in xml format and use it to produce the diagram maybe?

Comment: So why don't you ask this?